# Oracle on Mac OSX, access from a virtual machine

Tags: macos, oracle, osx-snow-leopard, virtualization, virtual-machine

I've installed Oracle on Mac OSX Snowleopard following the [guide of Raimonds Simanovskis](http://blog.rayapps.com/2009/09/14/how-to-install-oracle-database-10g-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/), as far as I know the only working installation guide for Snowleopard.

As long as I use Oracle only on the Mac under MacOX itself, it works well, no problems.

Now I have a virtual machine on the Mac (Parallels Desktop 5), and in this VM Windows XP is running. I want to access the Oracle database, which is running on Mac OSX, from the VM under Windows. Logically it is like accessing from a different computer. But always when I try to access from XP, for example with sqlplus

```
sqlplus iwes/iwes@192.168.3.2:1521/dbname
```

(192.168.3.2 it the address of MacOS using 'Host only networking'. This address is working well in other applications.)
then I get the error message

```
ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS: Kein Listener    [German for: "no listener"]
```

(on Mac OSX both Oracle and the listener are started and working)

What is wrong or missing in my Oracle installation?

Here is my listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = dbname)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1)
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = dbname)
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

and my tnsnames.ora

```
dbname =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = dbname)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC0))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your listener.ora should specify 192.168.3.2 as host, instead of localhost.

your tnsnames.ora should specify 192.168.3.2 as host for alias dbname (if you use tnsnames.ora at all)
In your example you don't use tnsnames.ora but jump directly to the mac's ip-address.
Also check the firewall on the mac.

Comment: Bingo! That was it. Changing the host name solved the problem. (I still think it's not logical, because localhost and 192.168.3.2 are the same computer, but that's nothing we need to discuss about.)

Comment: No. localhost should always be 127.0.0.1